# AWS API Gateway VPC Link to ELB returning Service Unavailable with HTTP503 in ApiGateway logs but nothing in ELB Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, aws-elb

I'm having issues with setting up an AWS API Gateway VPC Link to an existing ELB in order to make a private endpoint public.

The error I receive when browsing to the API Gateway endpoint is `{"message":"Service Unavailable"}`

Here's  project setup.

1. EC2 instances within a private VPC
2. EC2 added to a target group with port 80 listener
3. ELB created with two rules: 1) HTTP:80 to HTTPS:443 2)HTTPS to target group in #2
4. The Sec Groups used by the EC2 allow HTTP access only from the ELB
5. The Sec Group on the ELB allows HTTPS traffic from specific IPs
6. VPC Link created for the same VPC as #1, all 3 subnets included. New Sec Group created allowing HTTPS traffic from all.
7. Sec Group in #5 (ELB) set to allow HTTP and HTTPS requests from SecGroup created in #6 (VPC Link)
8. HTTP API Gateway created
9. API Gateway Route created, /sample/{proxy+}, using an integration setup as a Private Resource, ALB/BLB, pointing at the ELB in #3, with a listener of HTTP (also tried HTTPS), method of ANY, and the VPC LInk set to the link created in #6
10. Cloudwatch logs enabled for the API Gateway $default stage
11. ELB Logging enable to S3.

The main platform works fine for people connecting via HTTPs via the ELB however any requests to the API Gateway endpoint wait for while then return the HTTP503 response with the body of `{"message":"Service Unavailable"}`

Cloudwatch logs show the HTTP503 response but do not give any other useful pieces of information.
The ELBs logs show no requests coming in with the requested URL.

The results appear as if the VPC Link is not working and the request to the ELB is being rejected by the Security Group on the ELB even when the ELB's SecGroup is set to allow "All Traffic" from the SecGroup used by the VPC Link.

I'm at a lost as to what could be causing the issue and am hoping that someone can spot something I've missed along the way.

I've followed the various AWS Docs including:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-stages.html
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-private.html
3. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vpc-links.html

None of these mention the SecGroup setup

I have been successful when I create a HTTP URI integration and point that at a endpoint that allows public requests. This is no good though as the application needs to remain private other than one or two endpoints.

Everything I've read suggests that the API Gateway -> VPC Link -> ELB -> EC2 approach should work

**UPDATE 1**

*VPC Link Setup*

1. The VPC is pointing to the same VPC that the EC2 instances are running in which is the same VPC as the ELB
2. All three subnets (172.30.0.0/20, 172.30.16.0/20 and 172.30.32.0/20) have been enabled.
3. It has it's own SecGroup

*API Gateway Integration*

Selection Method: Manual
Target Service: ALB/NLB
Load Balancer: SM-01-ELB
Listener: HTTP 80
VPC Link: SM01-VPC Link

Comment: I did this one a month ago and it will work on your side as well. And I think your baseline is nothing wrong. Can you attach some configurations image of vpc_link to ALB. I think your API GW is not routing traffic to the ALB. Can you check if you put VPC Link to private subnets, not the public one?

Comment: @AshBlake I agree with you about the GW not routing to the ELB. The VPCLink is using the same VPC as both the EC2 instances and the ELB.

The EC2's do have public IPs but they have SecGroup rules to restrict these to specific management IPs for SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vpc-links.html), it said:

> VPC links enable you to create private integrations that connect your HTTP API routes to private resources in a VPC

Did you create ALB and VPC Link located in private subnets? I assume you won't connect to ALB successfully if you use had placed it in private subnets.

And can you also check if VPC Link's ENI is created or not?

I need to put my questions here since comment section is quite small for me

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "I assume you won't connect to ALB successfully if you use had placed it in private subnets."?

Comment: I mean according to the docs, all your resources should be in private subnets, which mean behind a NAT Gateway. I guess that you are place all resources inside public subnet so that you can connect directly

Comment: I think you're right. Looking at them they appear to be public subnets which have been tied down. I'll create a new VPC for testing that's private to see if that works, if it does then I'll mark the answer as correct. It certainly would make sense

Comment: Please try ^^ I just did it a month ago and nothing wrong with your base

Comment: I've not had another chance to look but I have confirmed the setup is using public VPCs but I won't have a chance to change it for a while so I got around it using an API Gatway to Lambda with the lambda being in the VPC

Comment: What is the point of having lambda in between if those (subnets) are public? In this case, you could use APIG HTTP integration and point it to your LB

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of pain with this. I ultimately resolved it by following these [fantastic instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-private-integration.html).

Basically route your API Gateway to a NLB which routes to your ALB (on a particular listener) and make sure the NLB is only in private subnets. Now you can handle Authorization at the API Gateway and grant access to a private endpoint while still letting your ALB be public and route elsewhere with other listeners that don't need to be fronted by the NLB.